# Consult replicating values on digit cpf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-4-2-1

I have a search that when digit a CPF show all results. Ok, but I need that show this way:
(Just a person and the quantity of contracts that it has)
* My code is in portuguese, sorry

```
Name
Registry
CPF
   Contract 1 ---- Show all contracts
   Contract 2   --------
   Contract 3 -----------
```

But it is currently coming so:
(The same values according to the amount of contract)

```
Name
Registry
CPF
   Contract 1 ---- Show all contracts
   Contract 2   --------
   Contract 3 -----------

Name
Registry
CPF
   Contract 1 ---- Show all contracts
   Contract 2   --------
   Contract 3 -----------

Name
Registry
CPF
   Contract 1 ---- Show all contracts
   Contract 2   --------
   Contract 3 -----------
```

It is replicating values... because contract's number

My view is this:

```
<% if params[:pesquisa_func_cpf].present? %>
  <h4><b>Resultados</b></h4>
  <% @autorizacoes.each do |autorizacao| %>
    <table class="table table-condensed">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><%= autorizacao.employee.person.name %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Registry</th>
        <td><%= autorizacao.employee.registry %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>CPF</th>
        <td><%= autorizacao.employee.person.cpf %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
      <th>Contract number</th>
      <% @autorizacoes.each do |autorizacao| %>
        <td><%= autorizacao.number_contract %></td>
      <% end %>
    </table>

  <% end %>
<% end%>
```

In this is my controller:

if params[:pesquisa_func_cpf].present?
      @autorizacoes = Autorizacao.pesquisa_func_cpf(params[:pesquisa_func_cpf]).all

I try the .distinct instead of .all, but don't work : (

And my consult (I use oracle), is it:

```
select * from autorizacoes INNER JOIN employers ON employers.id = autorizacoes.employer_id
                           INNER JOIN people ON employers.person_id = people.id
                           WHERE people.cpf  LIKE '111.111.111-11'
```

And it return 3 results, according my example. Please, how make just leave this structure:

```
Name
Registry
CPF
   Contract 1 ---- Show all contracts
   Contract 2   --------
   Contract 3 -----------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! In my controller I just this:

```
if params[:pesquisa_func_cpf].present?
      @employers = Employee.pesquisa_cpf(params[:pesquisa_func_cpf]).all
      @autorizacoes = Autorizacao.pesquisa_func_cpf(params[:pesquisa_func_cpf]).all
```

And my view I remove <%= autorizacao.employee.person.name %> and put <%= employee.person.name %>

Just this and works!